# How Can I Build a Crystal Report on a Stored Procedure?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports-2010

I have a few dozen legacy Reports, many of them with Sql Server stored procedures as their data source.  I'm trying to use them in an application built with **VB.NET 2010** and **CR for Visual Studio 2010 version 13.0.2**.

When I run a report based on a stored procedure I get an error message saying something like

> The table 'REPORT_SCHEDULEB' could not be found

The table definition in the report looks like this:

```
LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo for REPORT_SCHEDULEB:
Name: "REPORT_SCHEDULEB", Location: "Proc(REPORT_SCHEDULEB;1)"
AllowCustomConnection: False, DBName: myDb, IntegratedSecurity: False
ServerName: myComputer, User: myName, Password: myPassword, Attributes:
    Database DLL: crdb_ado.dll
    QE_DatabaseName: myDb
    QE_DatabaseType: OLE DB (ADO)
        Auto Translate: -1
        Connect Timeout: 0
        Data Source: myComputer
        General Timeout: 0
        Initial Catalog: myDb
        Integrated Security: False
        Locale Identifier: 1033
        OLE DB Services: -5
        Provider: SQLOLEDB
        Tag with column collation when possible: 0
        Use DSN Default Properties: False
        Use Encryption for Data: 0
        Owner: dbo
    QE_ServerDescription: myComputer
    QE_SQLDB: True
    SSO Enabled: False
    Owner: dbo
```

I'm guessing that there's some issue with the way the *Location* field is defined, but

1. when I try to change the *Overridden Qualified Table Name* in the
   report editor it won't accept the change, and
2. I'd really rather find a programmatic solution than hand-edit dozens of reports.

So, I tried in my code to set the table.Location value, but that throws a COM exception -- I guess it's readonly at some level.

I also thought of the possibility of setting some sort of *QualifiedName* property but haven't found a way to do that.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved a solution in VB by setting the report datasource at runtime using a datatable created from a stored procedure.  That way, all the connection details need only be stored once within the application rather than against each report.

(roughly)

```
Dim SourceDatabase as datatable = GetDatatableFromSP(SPName)
Dim DocumentToShow as New ReportDocument

DocumentToShow.Load(DocumentPath)
DocumentToShow.SetDataSource(SourceDatabase)

ReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = DocumentToShow
```